# UICollectionViewCell Framing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

This seems like it would be a straightforward answer but I cannot find it anywhere.

I am having trouble framing various UI objects within my UICollectionViewCell. And I am **NOT** using AutoLayout (as for me it causes more problems than it solves) 
This is what my CollectionView currently looks like...

[image]

As you can see the UIImageView for example is set to a variation of `cell.contentView.bounds`. This should have a dynamic width that matches the width of the cells content view, and a predefined height. In another place where this is incorrect is the comment in the second cell *'OH YEAH'* should sit at the bottom of the cell and again its width should be the dynamic width of the cells content view.

I have tried it setting this frame value in both the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, **AND** the `willDisplayCell` (which in UITableView this would work) however it seems to thing the bounds of the cell are different, or not yet set to their new sizes.

Is the `collectionViewLayout` been called **after** the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, if so **why**?

The hight of the cell are dynamic and are set in the `collectionViewLayout`

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return CGSizeMake(self.streamCollection.bounds.size.width - 30.0, DYNAMIC_HEIGHT);
}
```

Please help, I'm positive this is an easy fix I just cannot find the 'best' practise.

Comment: IF you are using storyboard, it isnt dificult to achieve autolayout by applying some basic constraints

Comment: You haven't explained what you don't like about the layout you have, so it's difficult for us to tell you what to change.

Comment: @Mr.T I am currently looking into constraints but for the purpose of this I must use the particular method as the rest of the project has been build without auto layout.

Comment: @robmayoff I have updated the post to state exactly what I am trying to achieve. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: “I am NOT using AutoLayout”—What are you using? Are you setting the autoresizing mask? Are you implementing `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: @robmayoff Autolayout is disabled in my project, so everything is programmatically framed. Where should I be using layoutSubviews?